# IoT DevKit Setup Issue: What Should I Select for Board Type?

Tags: azure, arduino, iot, devkit

I am currently setting up an MXChip (DevKit) for use with Azure by following the guide below:

https://microsoft.github.io/azure-iot-developer-kit/docs/get-started/

After configuring the device connection string, I cannot complete the subsequent step (Build and upload Arduino sketch) without having to select a board type. These are the options listed:

- Arduino Yun
- Arduino/Genuino Uno
- Arduino Duemilanove
- Arduino Nano
- Arduino/Genuino Mega
- Arduino Mega ADK
- Arduino Leonardo
- Arduino Leonardo ETH
- Arduino/Genuino Micro
- Arduino Esplora
- Arduino Mini
- Arduino Ethernet
- Arduino Fio
- Arduino BT
- LilyPad Arduino USB
- LilyPad Arduino
- Arduino Pro
- Arduino NG or Older
- Arduino Robot Control
- Arduino Robot Motor
- Arduino Gemma
- Adafruit Circuit Playground
- Arduino Yun Mini
- Arduino Industrial 101
- Linino One
- Arduino Uno WiFi

I am unsure of which option to choose. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you installed the "DevKit Board Package" ?

Comment: Yes, I successfully ran the install.cmd in the given zip file.

Comment: I don't have a setup here so I have no way of knowing if that's the same thing. Check it with the BoardManager.

Comment: I checked board manager and while I did have an MXChip board package installed, I didn't have the most updated version. I installed that and it appeared as an option on the list. Thank you!

Comment: Good. You can now post a self-answer for posterity. You could also leave a reaction on that ms page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type F1, and then enter Arduino: Board Manager into the action line to view board packages. Installing the newest edition of the MXChip Board Package will cause that package to appear as an option in the board type list.

I also ran into a subsequent compiling error in which the terminal indicated:

**"exec: "/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++": file does not exist"**

Installing the Arduino Zero Board Package from the board manager solved this error.